# Mule Web Service Consumer MustUnderstand header

Tags: web-services, soap, mule, cxf

I've built a flow the sends requests to an external web service consumer. Security is enabled on this service I have configured it as so

```
<ws:consumer-config name="Test_WS" wsdlLocation="test.wsdl" service="TestService" port="TestServicePort" serviceAddress="http://${service.host}:${service.port}/test/services" connectorConfig="HttpsConnector" doc:name="Web Service Consumer">
    <ws:security>
        <ws:wss-username-token username="${service.user}" password="${service.pwd}" passwordType="TEXT"/>
    </ws:security>
</ws:consumer-config>
```

When a request is sent, a SOAP fault is thrown:

```
Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.module.ws.consumer.SoapFaultException: Did not understand "MustUnderstand" header(s):. Message payload is of type: ElementNSImpl
at org.mule.module.ws.consumer.WSConsumer$1.processNext(WSConsumer.java:196)
```

Is there a way to disable the MustUnderstand header? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The header, **mustUnderstand**, has a default value of *true*.

Set this header to *false* by setting a message property before calling the WebService Consumer. This should solve this.

```
<set-property propertyName="mustUnderstand" value="false"/>
```